# Just 212 GB Can be found out of 1 TB in my Ubuntu server 22.04.2

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I  recently installed **Ubuntu 22.04.2**. I was using **Windows 10** previously. During installation, I chose to  **Erase all options** to delete all my Windows files.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iEvv.png)

I have a **1 TB hard disk** but after installation, only 212 GB is showing. But when I type `lsblk` the following information is showing which proves that I have 930 GB of space.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tNxm.png)

Then when I type `sudo fdisk -l` you can see the space is available in hard disk.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otOni.png)

**PLease help me fix this.**

Comment: I must be missing something. In both the 2nd and 3rd image you posted, `/dev/sda3` shows 931.5Gb. And nowhere do I see a partition with 212Gb. But I do see `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, which shows 238Gb. Please explain again what your problem is with more detail.

Comment: Your image says that your system has two storage devices: sda is 931 GB. nvme0n1 is 238 GB. Your image says that you installed Ubuntu to the smaller device. Did you intend differently?